# efficient numpy array creation

Tags: python, numpy

Given `x`, I want to produce `x, log(x)` as a numpy array whereby `x` has shape `s`, the result has shape `(*s, 2)`.  What's the neatest way to do this?  `x` may just be a float, in which case I want a result with shape `(2,)`.

An ugly way to do this is:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray(x)
result = np.empty((*x.shape, 2))
result[..., 0] = x
result[..., 1] = np.log(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to separate aesthetics from performance. Sometimes ugly code is
fast.  In fact, that's the case here. Although creating an empty array and then
assigning values to slices may not look beautiful, it is fast.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit 
import itertools as IT
import pandas as pd

def using_empty(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    result = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
    result[..., 0] = x
    result[..., 1] = np.log(x)
    return result

def using_concat(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return np.concatenate([x, np.log(x)], axis=-1).reshape(x.shape+(2,), order='F')

def using_stack(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return np.stack([x, np.log(x)], axis=x.ndim)

def using_ufunc(x):
    return np.array([x, np.log(x)])
using_ufunc = np.vectorize(using_ufunc, otypes=[np.ndarray])

tests = [np.arange(600),
         np.arange(600).reshape(20,30),
         np.arange(960).reshape(8,15,8)]

# check that all implementations return the same result
for x in tests:
    assert np.allclose(using_empty(x), using_concat(x))
    assert np.allclose(using_empty(x), using_stack(x))


timing = []
funcs = ['using_empty', 'using_concat', 'using_stack', 'using_ufunc']
for test, func in IT.product(tests, funcs):
    timing.append(timeit.timeit(
        '{}(test)'.format(func), 
        setup='from __main__ import test, {}'.format(func), number=1000))

timing = pd.DataFrame(np.array(timing).reshape(-1, len(funcs)), columns=funcs)
print(timing)
```

yields, the following timeit results on my machine:

```
   using_empty  using_concat  using_stack  using_ufunc
0     0.024754      0.025182     0.030244     2.414580
1     0.025766      0.027692     0.031970     2.408344
2     0.037502      0.039644     0.044032     3.907487
```

So `using_empty` is the fastest (of the options tested applied to `tests`).

Note that `np.stack` does exactly what you want, so

```
np.stack([x, np.log(x)], axis=x.ndim)
```

looks reasonably pretty, but it is also the slowest of the three options tested.

---

Note that along with being much slower, `using_ufunc` returns an array of object dtype:

```
In [236]: x = np.arange(6)

In [237]: using_ufunc(x)
Out[237]: 
array([array([  0., -inf]), array([ 1.,  0.]),
       array([ 2.        ,  0.69314718]),
       array([ 3.        ,  1.09861229]),
       array([ 4.        ,  1.38629436]), array([ 5.        ,  1.60943791])], dtype=object)
```

which is not the same as the desired result:

```
In [240]: using_empty(x)
Out[240]: 
array([[ 0.        ,        -inf],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  0.69314718],
       [ 3.        ,  1.09861229],
       [ 4.        ,  1.38629436],
       [ 5.        ,  1.60943791]])

In [238]: using_ufunc(x).shape
Out[238]: (6,)

In [239]: using_empty(x).shape
Out[239]: (6, 2)
```

Comment: I like `stack` best actually.  I don't usually optimize my Python code for speed :)

Comment: Would you mind adding the `@ufunc` decorator as another way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `@ufunc` decorator. Are you referring to [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-June/126864.html)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how that would work. My naive attempt, `def using_ufunc(x): return x, np.log(x)`; `using_ufunc = np.vectorize(using_ufunc)`; `using_ufunc(np.arange(6))` returns a tuple of arrays, not the desired result. Do you see how it can be done with `np.vectorize`?

Comment: That's what I thought would work.   I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added it to your answer, but would you mind timing it?

Comment: I've added the timing, but note that `using_ufunc` returns an object array of the wrong shape -- so the timings are an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Comment: I noticed that vectorize is returning an object array.   I feel like that's a bug.  Thanks for your help by the way.